# How to Bundle Adjustment in c#?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need to use bundle adjustment optimization in my stereovision project. I am using `EmguCV` library in my project. I found documantation for BA function [EmguCV BA function](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/html/d851496e-bd89-ec5b-b123-0de554804210.htm) but it looks old and i cant find this function in EmguCV new documentation. Is there are any way to do BA in `c#` using `EmguCv` or maybe another librarys exist?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/d46/group__stitching.html

Comment: @HansPassant I think its not exactly what i wanted. I know about BA functions in OpenCV but its C/С++ lib.